# is it possible to do a query inside a tasks.py with celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Totally new to celery and wondering if you can run a query on a table inside a celery task?

celery is working and i can queue jobs, however, i tried this and it gives an error:

```
import celery
from celery import shared_task

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from frontendapp.models import xlinkdatabase

@shared_task
def lookup(lookup_id):
    look_up_result = get_object_or_404(xlinkdatabase,MEMBER_ID=lookup_id)
    return look_up_result
```

error:

```
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'xlinkdatabase' is not JSON serializable
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The thing is I am trying to go through a list of ID's (input in a csv file) and I want to add e-mail address to that ID and write that in a new CSV file. The ID / e-mail relation is in my psql xlinkdatabase model.

The whole idea of a lookup is not to return an object. I want to have a task that does a lookup in my psql database (related to the model) and picks one value from that specific search.

models.py:

```
class xlinkdatabase(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    MEMBER_ID = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Member id",max_digits=19, decimal_places=0,default=Decimal('0'))
    MEMBER_PRIMARY_EMAIL = models.CharField(verbose_name="Email address", max_length = 150, default="not set")
```

I want to return the `MEMBER_PRIMARY_EMAIL` address based on the `MEMBER_ID` I put in the task.

Comment: You can not return an object from the task. You have to return something that's serializable. Like you can convert your object to json

Comment: I edited my question so it is more clear. I don't want to return an object persé.

Comment: so what exactly are you returning? Is it a list of member primary email address? If so then also the answer below will work

Comment: thanks for the help, indeed, impossible to return the object, only a part, or a list.

Answer (score 0):

From celery docs

> Data transferred between clients and workers needs to be serialized, so every message in Celery has a content_type header that describes the serialization method used to encode it.

So you can't return an object from the celery worker.

**Solution**:

```
from django.core import serializers
import celery
from celery import shared_task

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from frontendapp.models import xlinkdatabase

@shared_task
def lookup(lookup_id):
    look_up_result = get_object_or_404(xlinkdatabase,MEMBER_ID=lookup_id)
    return serializers.serialize("json", look_up_result)
```